# Notice of possible eviction, no reason given and notice doesn't follow state law

Tags: united-states, contract-law, michigan

I'm 19 had a roommate (older brother) who split rent with me on our apartment. Couple months go by and they decided to get 2 cats (sent me a text while I'm at work because apparently my opinion doesn't matter). Not long after that they tell me they're joining the army, leaving me with the full rent and 2 cats and making me give up on going to college in favor of working more hours to pay bills.

They say "this is a courtesy letter" as if they're being kind by informing me of my impending state of homelessness.

Admittedly, I haven't paid the down payment nor the monthly payment for the cats but even then they don't even list that as the reason for my eviction, or any reason for that matter. I'm barely making ends meet and I'm already hundreds of dollars in debt so $3k is out of the question. I did a bit of googling and found [this](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/state-laws-termination-violation-lease.html):

> State Laws on Termination for Violation of Lease
>
> State laws typically vary depend on whether the reason for termination
>   is the tenant's nonpayment of rent or violation of a lease clause.
>   This chart covers the latter (termination for tenant violation of a
>   lease clause).

I think not paying for the cats qualifies as a violation of the lease.

> Many states give tenants a specified amount of time to cure or cease a lease or rental agreement violation or to move out before the landlord can file for eviction.

They didn't give me any time to "cure or cease a lease or rental agreement violation" at all, hell they didn't even give a reason. The section for Michigan (my state of residence) says:

> Mich. Comp. Laws § 600.5714
>
> For causing serious, continuous health hazards or damage to the premises: 7 days after receiving notice to restore or repair or quit (domestic violence victims excepted).

Wow! So instead of giving me 7 days to rid myself of the cats or start paying for them, they started the eviction immediately and gave me 3 days to fill their pockets for a change  of heart! I don't want to count my eggs before they've hatched so would someone please tell me this information is all correct and reliable, I've got nowhere to go if I get kicked out of here.

Comment: They reference a "judgement", were you already given a notice to appear in eviction court that you didn't appear in? You may want to ask them for a copy of this judgement, if you defaulted by not appearing you may have a judgement against you.

Comment: They should also be able to provide you an itemized bill that accounts for the full amount requested, specifically stating what it is for (fees, late fees, etc). The only way a balliff will show up though is if you were legally evicted through housing court.

Comment: @RonBeyer I did not receive anything, this is the first note posted to my door (they came over for "scheduled maintenance" which is literally never maintenance, this time  it was for the cats it would seem) I check my email and the only thing I received from them was a notification of my rent being paid.

Comment: @RonBeyer  I believe when they say my "judgement" expires on the 22nd they're referring to whether I've forked the cash or not

Comment: I'd say you will find a lawyer for much less than $2,700.

Comment: Check out https://michiganlegalhelp.org/self-help-tools/housing

Comment: Have you confirmed that this notice is real by talking to the housing office?

Comment: Yeah, that's a weird notice.  I checked their website, and they're very clear about being [pet-friendly](http://www.lexingtonvillageapartments.com/p/apartments/pet_friendly_8160/madison-heights-mi-48071/lexington-village-apartments-8160), pointing it out as one of their features on several of their pages, so it'd strange that they'd react like this by seeing two cats.  By the way, the letter shows everyone your address; perhaps want to fill-over your room number, at least?

Comment: @Nat I called the office a while ago and they'll look into it and give me further information tommorow

Comment: Is your brother still on the lease or a party to the eviction; and are they currently under active duty orders to report for training?  If yes the Servicemembers Civil Relief Act could delay the eviction proceeding, but your brother should seek the assistance of an Armed Forces Legal Assistance Program office if this is a possibility.   https://www.justice.gov/crt/servicemembers-civil-relief-act-summary

Comment: By saying "this is a courtesy letter"  they mean that this is not a formal legal notification, and at least imply that they didn't have a legal duty to send this letter. That may well be wrong,  but that iw what they are saying @Iñaki Viggers

Comment: While I have not (yet) voted to close this question, it really does fall under the "no specific legal advice rule" and should be rewritten to remove all the personal details, and be a general query that might be helpful to others as well as to the OP. If it isn't it will probably be closed. The OP urgently needs to get actual legal advice, as several comments have pointed out.

Comment: @DavidSiegel "*they [...] imply that they didn't have a legal duty to send this letter*". MCL 600.5714(1)(a) (link provided below) reflects the *requirement* of "*service of a written demand for possession*". Similarly, item (1)(e) of that statute ("*7 days following service of a written notice to quit for termination*"). Therefore, yes, the landlord's portrayal of the letter as mere "courtesy" would be wrong (if not procedurally improper).

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what ended up happening?  Was the notice real?  Did a bailiff come to pull you out of the apartment?

Comment: @Nat literally nothing happened afterwards. Main office told me they have no record of me owing them money and that a probably shouldn't worry about it meanwhile they offer no explanation for how the notice got on my door. I removed the image because my personal information was in the notice and I was to lazy to edit the photo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One has to be really despicable to *vote to close* this question, and yet some users did that already.

> they started the eviction immediately and gave me 3 days to fill their pockets

The landlord ought to comply with the notice period as mandated by statute. In [*Ypsilanti Housing Comm'n v. Oday*, 618 N.W.2d 18, 22 (2000)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/2000636618nw2d181633), the court concluded that "*the summary proceedings in the district court were premature, and thus defendant's resultant eviction was improper*" because the landlord did not comply with the [30-day] notice to which the defendant was entitled by statute.

The excerpt of [MCL 600.5714(1)(d)](http://www.legislature.mi.gov/(S(ndasjqpsj0tgnqbyajpssfuq))/mileg.aspx?page=getobject&objectname=mcl-600-5714) you reproduce seems inapplicable. The landlord would have a hard time proving that possession of two cats "*causes a serious and continuing health hazard to exist on the premises, or causes extensive and continuing physical injury to the premises*". Instead, the landlord's proceedings would seemingly be premised on MCL 600.5714(1)(a) and [MCL 554.134(1)](http://www.legislature.mi.gov/(S(nhoksbayypfxd04phhqd0lcu))/mileg.aspx?page=getobject&objectname=mcl-554-134).

> I think not paying for the cats qualifies as a violation of the lease.

Yes. Even if the lease does not define *rent* in a way that explicitly encompasses pet fees, it would be hard to defeat the landlord's argument that a *pet fee* meets the legal definition of rent (or the [statutory definition lease](http://www.legislature.mi.gov/(S(ndasjqpsj0tgnqbyajpssfuq))/mileg.aspx?page=getObject&objectName=mcl-600-5701)). The Black's Law Dictionary defines *rent* as the "*[c]onsideration paid for use or occupation of property*", and having pets certainly qualifies as *use of property*.

That being said, the amount of $2,759 seems too high for just a down payment and the monthly pet fee. Additional details of your situation would shed light on whether or not the landlord is violating the provision in MCL 600.5714(1)(a) that "*rent due does **not include any accelerated indebtedness** because of a breach of the lease under which the premises are held*" (emphasis added).

> They say "this is a courtesy letter" as if they're being kind by informing me of my impending state of homelessness.

I hear you. Calling it a "courtesy" is too inadequate to be considered part of the "good business practices".

Comment: I don't think one needs to be "really despicable" to vote to close a question pretty clearly in violation of the rules, specifically the rule against questions that ask for specific legal advice. OP's situation sounds very unpleasant, and OP needs useful help. But the problem is beyond what a site like this can really handle.

Comment: @DavidSiegel The OP is doing anything he can to solve an obviously stressful situation while you take issue with him being "*pretty clearly in violation of the rules [...] against questions that ask for specific legal advice*". His question harms no one. And instead of OP reacting to his problem negatively, he seeks to solve it **lawfully**, whence the least a prudent person could do is refrain from hindering the OP's search for starting points with which to overcome the hardship in which he has been thrown.

Comment: I am sorry for the OP's situation, which i agree is stressful, and seems to be unjust. I don't take issue with the OP, he or she is new to the site. But this site is really not able to give the kid of assistance the OP needs. And you as an experienced user here, should know that. You have convinced me that  leavign this question open will only extend false hope to the OP, and waste everyone's time. I have voted to close accordingly.

Comment: @DavidSiegel What really wastes everyone's time is to act like "watchdogs of specific legal advice" for the sake of closing questions. That approach will never direct the OP's attention to Michigan case law that reinforces his entitlement to statutorily sufficient notice; nor does that approach alert the OP on the issue of whether or not the amount of $2,759 illegally includes any *accelerated indebtedness*. The OP will need that information, especially if no lawyer bothers to represent ASAP a 19 y.o. person who has to give up college so he can work more hours to pay bills.

Comment: @SemperAmbroscus "*stackoverflow is just as bad if not worse*". Online anonymity comes with some of "bravery" and *herd effect* when it comes to censuring a user. The way things are, one can only acknowledge when at least someone comes forward and articulates his downvote. On the bright side, others adopt a more human approach, like the suggestions on michiganlegalhelp & Civil Relief Act, or RonBeyer's remark about judgment & itemized bill. Given landlord's delay of response and his choice of notice over a holiday weekend, you might also want to consider an argument of *equitable tolling*.

Comment: @SemperAmbroscus That letter appears to be threatening to forcibly remove you from your home in the very near future.  Not to be rough on you or anything, but that seems like something you should've physically visited their office for.  And I'm guessing that you could probably call the police department or whoever sends out a bailiff to confirm that one is, in fact, scheduled to come drag you away.  I really don't understand the lack of urgent fact-checking here.